# Is there an option to filter Revit elements based on a view on forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have multiple 3D views and user can select any views in the forge application to view. here i am trying to get the elements only associated to the selected view. from the view i am able to get the model and all the elements. But i am not able to filter based on the views as Revit do.
Is it possible to filter elements based on the selected view?

Appreciating you help.

Regards,
Durai

Answer (score 1):

Check the `__viewable_in__` property of the elements, it should indicate where the given element is visible and allow you, for instance, to navigate to other views, [like in this sample](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/navigating-between-2d-views).

Comment: Thank you Augusto. We tried with the _viewable_in. But it is showing all the objects in two different views. Am i missing something here?.

Comment: I would suggest trying with a sample model, like https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/getting-started/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/Revit-GetStarted/files/GUID-61EF2F22-3A1F-4317-B925-1E85F138BE88-htm.html so you can debug it. Not sure what king of model you have...